# What is the source of Eleven promises of Sai Baba

Tags: temple, saint, sai

11 promises of Sai baba are famous as Sai ke 11 vachan. But where is it mentioned in Sai Sachharitra? Which Chapter includes it? If it is not present in Sai Sachharitra, then where did it come from?

Comment: First of all, Chand Miyan (Sai Baba) is not a part of Hinduism. So asking this question here will fetch not any useful answer

Comment: Sai baba is known by a book called Sai Sachharitra. And Sai Sachharitra chapter 5, part 1 - tells that Chand Miya was a muslim who took Sai Baba with him to Shridi again at a marriage ceremony. Chand Miya and Sai Baba are two different people. I have given proof of my statement. But what proof do you have that he sai baba was Chand miya?? Do you have any source or reference for it??

Comment: Shirdi contains a majar which is not done for hindus, so it highlights the fact of Chand Miyan being Sai BAba of modern times

Comment: Majar is an urdu term for tomb. And tomb contains a grave. Even in Hinduism, children and saints, holy men are Not cremated but buried after their death. This is not unique to Sai Baba. Prabhu Paad ( founder of ISKCON) and Shankaraachaary were Buried, not burned after their death. This practice is common and ancient in Hinduism. You can search for it on internet that many of Hindu saints are buried and not cremated. And again, you didn't gave me any reference or source of your claim. Talk to me solely on the basis of scources

Comment: The samadhi sthala of Hindu Sadhus is circular and not a rectangle which is in Shirdi, the practice of making a rectangular tomb in seen only in Islam and nowhere in Hinduism. And the source for Chand Miyan being Sai is what I gave.

Comment: Amazing. Now a shape can decide to which religion the samadhi belongs. By that logic, green color belongs to muslim so dont eat anything green, cut down all the trees and dont worship goddess like Matangi and Lalita Tripur Sundari.By your logic, circular domes belong to mosques. So what about Hindu temples which have circular Dome?? Are they mosques now?? And you did not provide ANY written source that Sai baba and Chand miya are same person, but I have already provided clear proof that they are two different people. Your arguments without documented source won't win you anything

Comment: What proof do you have that it is Bogus? Sai Sachharitra was written by Hemadpanth when he used to live in Shirdi when Sai baba was alive. So there is little to no chance of interpolation or as other people at the time also contributed to it's writing.;The lesser the gap between the generation writing the events and the one about whom it's written, the higher the chance of authenticity. And in case of Sai baba, Hemadpanth lived with Sai baba so he of the first generation and hence his book Sai Sacharitra has the highest chance of authenticity. What proofs do you have that it's bogus??